# How do I add padding from top and bottom to a container when the background is a video in html

Tags: html, css, frontend

[image: This is it]

Heres my code I am trying, I want to add some padding between the top/bottom and container but I am unable to. I did use `padding-top` but it did not work out, and instead gave padding inside the container while I wanted it to be outside, I want the background video to still stay there and make up the background while making space between the container and top/bottom sides

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Health blog</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="...">
    <style>
        html{
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }
        body {
            font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            min-height: 100vh;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
        }
        video {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
            z-index: -1;
        }
        .container {
            background-color: #00ff00;
            background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #00ff00 0%, #69ff69 100%);
            border-radius: 10px;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            padding: 30px;
            max-width: 700px;
            text-align: center;
            z-index: 1;
            padd

        }
        .profile-pic {
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            object-fit: cover;
            margin: 20px auto;a
        }
        h1 {
            color: #fff;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        p {
            color: #fff;
            line-height: 1.6;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <video autoplay muted loop>
        <source src="..." type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div class="container">
        <img class="..." alt="Profile Picture">
        <h1>Navigating Your Path to Vibrant Health and Wellness</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: The code you provided is not giving the same case that you have, would it be okay to share the code from the screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `margin` instead of `padding` to give top/bottom spacing outside the container.

```css
.container {
  background-color: #00ff00;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #00ff00 0%, #69ff69 100%);
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 30px;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 30px 0; 
}
```

`margin:30px 0` will apply `30px` margins to the top and bottom and `0` to the left  and right